# Rails naming convention issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, naming-conventions

My question pertains to a Rails naming convention conundrum. My application has sign up, sign in, sign out features.

For the sign up page, I used `form_for(@user)` helper.

For the sign in page I used a `form_for(:session, url: sessions_path)`. But in my routes.rb file I have included the `resources :sessions` instead of the singular as mentioned in the argument of form_for helper in the sign in page.

If someone could:

1.) Solve this particular form_for issue

```
2.) More importantly point me in the direction where I can learn/read about Rails naming conventions, I would be highly indebted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I bet that @user has been initialized with `User.new` - this is a new user. When you sign up you want to create a new user so you can translate form_for(@user) as "form for a new user". Note that in this case you provide form_for an ActiveRecord User instance, which is the way it was meant to be used.
2. When you give form_for a symbol and not an instance of an ActiveRecord model, it uses the symbol to nest the inputs inside the form. For example, if you put `<%= f.text :name %>` in your form it will generate `<input name="session[name]" type="text">`. Also, when an existing user signs in you do not want to create a new user(like in step 1), you just want to create a new session for an existing user, thus posting to sessions_path looks very intuitive.
3. You can type the command `rake routes` in your terminal and get all the named routes set for your application, this will give you a very good insight of how rails converts the resources command into named routes.

For further info read the following:

[Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

[form_for ApiDock documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: So you are essentially saying that there is no correlation between the :session symbol in the form_for helper and the resources :sessions? And I could call the argument anything, i.e. form_for(:foobar, sessions_path)?

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying